# Calling a unique function based on matrix row and col index

Tags: algorithm, perl

Calling a unique function based on matrix row and col index

There are three views

```
ViewA
ViewB
ViewC
```

a user can switch from `ViewX` to `ViewY`. There is a different way to switch from X and Y. e.g. Switching from A to B is through one way while from B to A will be through some different way.

I am trying to write a generic function for it. As I can understand, these three views makes a total of 6 combinations (A-B, A-C, B-A, B-C, C-A, C-B)

```
           ViewA    ViewB   ViewC
    ViewA    X         2        3
    ViewB    4         X        6
    ViewC    7         8        X
```

What I am thinking that I will register specific function to given move. e.g. if move is from ViewA to ViewB then I will register function `SwitchViewA_to_viewB()` to the 2nd index.

Please let me know if we can have some other better approach to achive it. This is just an example with three view. In my actual case, I have almost 10 such views.

Comment: In perl I would do it as a dispatch table, but perhaps you could also check out the [State design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern).

Comment: stevenl - This is really great to use the state design pattern in my case. Thanks for exploring this idea!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's called a dispatch table.

```
my %switchers = (
   ViewA => { ViewB => \&SwitchViewA_to_viewB,
              ViewC => \&SwitchViewA_to_viewC, },
   ViewB => { ViewA => \&SwitchViewB_to_viewA,
              ViewC => \&SwitchViewB_to_viewC, },
   ViewC => { ViewA => \&SwitchViewC_to_viewA,
              ViewB => \&SwitchViewC_to_viewB, },
);

$switchers{$from}{$to}->()
   if $from ne $to;
```

or

```
my %switchers = (
   "ViewA-ViewB" => \&SwitchViewA_to_viewB,
   "ViewA-ViewC" => \&SwitchViewA_to_viewC,
   "ViewB-ViewA" => \&SwitchViewB_to_viewA,
   "ViewB-ViewC" => \&SwitchViewB_to_viewC,
   "ViewC-ViewA" => \&SwitchViewC_to_viewA,
   "ViewC-ViewB" => \&SwitchViewC_to_viewB,
);

$switchers{"$from-$to"}->()
   if $from ne $to;
```

Note that you can pass arguments to the function by passing them within the parens (as usual).

---

If you have 10 views, that means to say you have 90 functions.

Are you sure that's the way to you want to approach this issue? You should perhaps consider an approach that doesn't require knowing the previous view. Perhaps you can have two functions per view. One that's called to activate the view, and another to deactivate it.

Then you only need to 20 functions instead of 90. And adding an eleventh view would only require writing 2 functions instead of 20.

Comment: Yes, as I mentioned in my post, this is what I am doing. I am looking for any more feasible way of doing that (if possible).

Comment: Thanks for your second response. It is really helpful. It's reducing function count.

Answer (score 1):

In Java you could create "function" objects, store them in a collection (a map of maps for example), get the corresponding one for the combination you have and execute.

Function interface, actual functions implement this:

```
interface SwitchViewFunction() {
  void switchView(View from, View to);
}
```

In your view switching code:

```
Map<View,Map<View,SwitchViewFunction>> map = ...;

map.get(from).get(to).switchView(from, to);
```

Note that in the code above there are no checks (e.g. for null etc.), those are left as an excersise for you.

Also note that to use `View` as a key it should have reasonable implementations of `hashCode()` and `equals(...)`.